# How to extract content from xsd appinfo element in java

Tags: xsd, xmlbeans

I have an xsd with annotation elements that in turn contain the appinfo element. I am using the appinfo element to pass in the some custom information about the schema and need to extract the contents of the appinfo while I am traversing through the element.

Snippet from the xsd.

```
<xsd:element name = "Entity">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:appinfo>EntityReference</xsd:appinfo>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element
                            minOccurs = "0"
                            name = "Id"
                            type = "tns:guid"/>
                        <xsd:element
                            minOccurs = "0"
                            name = "LogicalName"
                            nillable = "true"
                            type = "xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element
                            minOccurs = "0"
                            name = "Name"
                            nillable = "true"
                            type = "xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
```

This is the code that I am using to extract the application information from the annotation.

```
SchemaAnnotation annotation = element.getAnnotation();
                            if(annotation!=null){
                                XmlObject[] ai = annotation.getApplicationInformation();
                                for(XmlObject obj : ai){
                                    if(obj!=null){
                                        //System.out.println(obj.toString());
                                        obj.getDomNode().getNodeValue();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

But I get a null value. The obj.toString() however returns this

```
<xml-fragment xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:request="http://ns1" xmlns:tns="http://ns2">EntityReference</xml-fragment>
```

How do I get the content "EntityReference" from appinfo? Am I suppose to write a custom handler to parse the string content?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

                                        Document document = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(obj.toString().getBytes()));
                                        NodeList list = document.getChildNodes();
                                        Node node = list.item(0); 

                                        if (node.getFirstChild() != null
                                                && node.getFirstChild().getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                                            //Text tn = (Text) node.getFirstChild();

                                            System.out.println(node.getFirstChild().getTextContent());
                                        }
```